# filter code in java for country - state-city using jcombobox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

in my project i want select fill the jcombobox which are have for COUNTRY,STATE,CITY 
when i click on counrty then it should be appear related in that country how many sate are have and then same thing with state also for city

here is my code tell me where is wrong and what it'll be right code for this

```
private void cmbcountryPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                        
       try{
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"hello");
            String sql= "SELECT StateName From state where Country_Id=? ";
            prst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            prst.setString(1, cmbcountry.getSelectedItem().toString());
            prst.execute();
            rs=prst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){                   
                    cmbstate.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("state"));                        
            }
        } catch(Exception e)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }

       fillstate(cmbcountry.getSelectedIndex());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but i think you have three comboboxes. Country, State and City and you want to populate States on the basis of Country selected and Cities on the basis of State selected. 
If that is what you want then the easiest option would be:
//notice the use of while instead of if as there would be multiple values

```
cmbstate.removeAllItems();
Vector<String> items = new Vector<String>();
while(rs.next())
{                   
   items.addElement(rs.getString("state"));                        
}
ComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(items);
cmbState.setModel(model);
```

Similarly for the city combobox when state is selected.

Creating a new Model everytime is not the best way so another option could be call `cmbState.addItem(String);` from wihin the loop. 
In any case you may need to remove the listeners from the combobox you are playing with as the listeners are fired when you make any changes in the data. You can do something like:

ItemListener[] itemListeners = cmbState.getItemListeners();
for(ItemListener l: itemListeners )
   cmbState.removeItemListener(l);
//do what you want with the combo here.
for(ItemListener l: itemListeners )
   cmbState.addItemListener(l);